# How to maintain proper variable scope/value in function call nested in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, scope

I ran into a scope problem when dealing with generated HTML plus event handling from within a loop.

**Imagine this scenario**

```
# var container=$('#someContainerId');

_buildField=function(index){
    return $('<div/>').data('index', index);
};

for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
    container.append( $('<div/>').on('click', function(){
        _buildField(i);
    } );
}
```

In this example, `_buildField()` will always receive the value `10`, no matter which of the `div` elements is being clicked.

Quite honestly, i thought it to be different, but here we go again, learning something new.

**QUESTION**

How can i assure the passing of the correct value (current iteration stored in `i`) to `_buildField()`?

Comment: This is not a duplicate for the linked question. Please ready carefully and compare the code situations. The solutions presented in the linked answer will not work in the situation explained in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES6**

If you can use ES6, opting for `let` instead of `var` may do the trick.

**ES5**

Since you said you need to use ES5, applying the IIFE pattern should solve your problem. Here's a contrived example:

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 0);
    })(i);
}
```

Adapting the above to your specific case should lead to:

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        container.append( $('<div/>').on('click', function(){
            _buildField(i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Cannot rely on ES6 unfortunately.

Comment: I tried to tackle the issue using ES5